# Passing only coordinates on click ".ie. remove text" using Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Below is my map script, everything is working pretty fantastic! However, when I click and it sends the e.latlng to the form it is sending

`LatLng(38.47939, -105.86426)` for example. I would prefer that it only send `38.47939, -105.86426`.

How can I remove the text and parentheses?

```
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([38.47939, -99.49219], 5);

L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v10/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiYnJldHQyMjI3OCIsImEiOiJjajAzNzZjZTkwOWNtMzJxbHZjMmVwZ2hyIn0.cWzkt6Gj_N3SZ8GKzqhByA', {
    }).addTo(mymap);

    var popup = L.popup();

    function onMapClick(e) {
    document.getElementById('lat-lng').value = e.latlng.toString();
        popup
            .setLatLng(e.latlng)
            .setContent("Copy and Paste into the Form \n" + e.latlng.toString())
            .openOn(mymap);

    }

    mymap.on('click', onMapClick);


</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If  you `console.log(e.latlng)` and observe the output, you will see that `e.latlng` is an object with two properties: `{ lat, lng }`. Thus we can output latitude and longitude independently and concatenate them to a string:

```
e.latlng.lat + ', ' + e.latlng.lng // '37.75334401310659, -107.09472656250001'
```

---

Using [ES6 template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) ([doesn't work in Internet Explorer](https://caniuse.com/#feat=template-literals)) you could do the following:

```
`${e.latlng.lat}, ${e.latlng.lng}` // slightly more readable
```

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to save `e.latlng.toString` to a new variable and clean up the data from there. something like:

```
var myLL=e.latlng.toString();
var myC=myLL.substring(7,myLL.length-1).split(',');
return myC[0].trim + myC[1].trim;
```

there may very well be a simpler builtin way to do this...